# Get row that has some specific conditions

Tags: c#, sql

I've got 2 tables

Table 1 has a detail of progress of assignment in table 2

Table 1. Assignment

```
ID | Class | Content | StudentID | LastReviewDate
..............
3133        GC      ABCD        1059     4/6/2018 17:35
```

Table 2. Detail

MondayOfWeekDate here is begin day of the week

```
AssignmentID | MondayOfWeekDate | Percent | StudentID | LastReviewDate
3133          3/19/2018          0        1059      3/23/2018 17:20
3133          4/2/2018          100       1689      4/7/2018 10:35
..............
```

I tried to write SQL to indicate between 3/26/2018 to 4/1/2018 to show assignment 3133 in that week but failed

```
SELECT Assignment.* FROM Assignment,Detail
WHERE Assignment.Class = 'GC'
AND Assignment.ID=Detail.AssignmentID
AND Detail.MondayOfWeekDate >'2018/03/26'
AND Percent<100
```

Of course the result was nothing but i can't find the right code to execute

Can you please me how to write SQL to show that information properly ? Thank you a lot.

Comment: what is `PhanTram`?

Comment: Your date formats are confusing, but I do not see a single date between March 26th and April 1st in any of your data. That said, you are not looking between two dates anyway, contrary to what you say in your text. If "PhanTram" is the numbers 0 and 100 in your details table, than the only record with "Phantram" < 100 is the one with two dates before March 26th, so it makes total sense you get no results.

Comment: @JaimeDrq it's 'percent'. PhanTram is in my native meaning. I fixed it

Comment: @oerkelens i am trying to find to look between 2 dates and to tell that assignment still in progress but i can't figure out the way

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Assignment.* FROM Assignment,Detail
WHERE Assignment.Class = 'GC'
AND Assignment.ID=Detail.AssignmentID
AND Detail.MondayOfWeekDate BETWEEN '2018-03-26' and  '2018-04-01'
AND Percent<100
```

You will get no results as there is nothing between 3/26/2018 to 4/1/2018??

The only mistake you made is your date which is to use between and its a better idea to use iso formatted date yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: But in 4/2/2018 the assignment is finished so 3/26/2018 and 4/1/2018, the assignment must be in progress and i can't find the way to display it

Comment: Your understanding of SQL is incorrect, SQL returns rows that exist in the database, it cant pull out rows that does not exist in the database such as in between.. between  3/26/2018 to 4/1/2018 there is no rows, SQL will not return anything, it doesnt know what is in progress

Answer (score 0):

I cannot directly speak to why you don't see anything.  But I can suggest how to write a more readable and maintainable query.  This *might* fix your problems but I don't know.

Some simple guidelines:

- Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- Always use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- Use table aliases.
- Use standard date formats.

So, start with a query like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Assignment a JOIN
     Detail d
     ON a.ID = d.AssignmentID
WHERE a.Class = 'GC' AND
      d.MondayOfWeekDate > '2018-03-26' AND
      d.Percent < 100;
```

Also check for syntax errors when you run the query.  It can be easy to make small errors that cause the query not to run.

Answer (score 0):

Your query fails because the row

```
3133          4/2/2018          100       1689      4/7/2018 10:35
```

Is the one bigger than `>'2018/03/26'` but its Percent is not `<100`, but 100. 
What are you exactly looking for?